# How do I pass objects from the request map into a method expression after rendering a component?

Tags: jsf, custom-component

I'm writing a custom datatable component, and I'm trying to allow other developers to use the var of the current iteration to be passed to a method expression.

Here's an example:

```
<my:dataTable value="#{contactController.viewEntities}" var="contact">
            <p:column headerText="Whatever">
                <p:commandButton value="Edit" 
                                 ajax="false"
                                 actionListener="#{contactController.setSelectedContact(contact)}"
                                 action="contact"/>
            </p:column>
</my:dataTable>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass the "contact" var into a setter method for later use. That var is stored in the request map during rendering, like so:

```
...
Map<String, Object> requestMap = context.getExternalContext()
                .getRequestMap();
for (Object obj : collection) { 
    requestMap.put(table.getVar(), obj);
    for (UIColumn column : columns) {

        column.encodeAll(context);

    }
    requestMap.remove(table.getVar());
}
...
```

**However, when I run the project, the only value passed to the controller is null.**

The question becomes, how do I make that object available for each row to use in expression language? I've looked at PrimeFaces'/ICEFaces' datatables, but I don't see how they differ from mine

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you surrounded your dataTable with <h:form> component?

Comment: Yes, the table is surrounded with a form. I'm trying to find the correlation between row request map data and form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally solved this issue! When extending UIData, the method `setRowIndex(index)` becomes available. By setting this value, the `clientId` of each row's component will be prepended with the index number, thus making them unique per row. The trick was to set this value while iterating over the underlying collection. Expression language can now evaluate the var parameters.

```
int index = 0;
Map<String, Object> requestMap = context.getExternalContext()
            .getRequestMap();
for (Object obj : collection) { 
    requestMap.put(table.getVar(), obj);
    table.setRowIndex(index);
    for (UIColumn column : columns) {

         column.encodeAll(context);

    }
    requestMap.remove(table.getVar());
    index ++;
}
```